# Google Cloud Composer DataflowJavaOperator: 403 Forbidden When Creating Job in Another Project

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to use DataflowJavaOperator on our testing composer environment, but  I am running into a `403 forbidden` error. My intention is to kick off a Dataflow Java job *on a different project* using the test composer environment.

```
t2 = DataFlowJavaOperator(
        task_id = "run-java-dataflow-job",
        jar="gs://path/to/dataflow-jar.jar",
        dataflow_default_options=config_params["dataflow_default_options"],
        gcp_conn_id=config_params["gcloud_config"]["conn_id"],
        dag=dag
)
```

My default options look like

```
'dataflow_default_options': {
  'project': 'other-project',
  'input': 'other-project:dataset.table',
  'output': 'other-project:dataset.table'
  ...
}
```

I have tried creating a temporary composer test environment in the same project as the Dataflow, and this allows me to use DataflowJavaOperator as expected. Only when the composer environment resides in a different project as the Dataflow, does DataflowJavaOperator not work as expected.

My current workaround is to use BashOperator, use "env" to set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS as gcp_conn_id path, store the jar file in our test composer bucket, and just run this bash command:

```
java -jar /path/to/dataflow-jar.jar \ 
[... all Dataflow job options]
```

Is it possible to use DataflowJavaOperator to kick off Dataflow jobs on another project?

Answer (score 1):

You need a different GCP connection created for Composer to interact with your 2nd GCP project and you need to pass that connection id to `gcp_conn_id` in `DataFlowJavaOperator`

Comment: Just edited. Using BashOperator, I am able to run the Dataflow job if I set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the same path as the GCP connection I used in the DataflowJavaOperator. It seems like the GCP connection is just fine.

Comment: Alternatively, you may add a Dataflow IAM policy binding to the service account used by your Composer environment so that it has permissions on the other project.